# Adding a column value by using DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

Using C# & MySQL

When I select the combobox value, the corresponding value should display in textbox

C# Code.

```
cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("Select name from users where username='" + cmbuser.Text  + "'", con);
dr= cmd2.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    txtusername.Text = dr("user");
}
```

The Above code is working in VB.Net, but in C# showing error as Error "dr' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method' "

It is showing error in this line `txtusername.Text = dr("user");`

How to solve this error, what problem in my code.

Need C# Code Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need to use `txtusername.Text = dr.GetString(0);` instead of your error line...

Answer (score 4):

Use the rectangular brackets in c#:

```
txtusername.Text = dr["user"];
```

Edit: You have to cast the object to the desired type after.

Comment: this will return type `object`